# does MySQL executes single statement atomically?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-deadlocks

say, i have 2 connections and they are executing following code.
can it lead to deadlock?

```
connection 1-> lock tables A write, B write;
connection 2-> lock tables B write, A write;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could eliminate the risk of deadlock by using `LOCK TABLES A WRITE, B WRITE;` in both connections. This is atomic, so the second connection would wait.

If you don't use `LOCK TABLES`, there's a risk of deadlock.

Even a single SQL statement can deadlock in certain cases. We see this frequently at my current workplace, for example, if a table has more than one primary or unique key. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  x INT,
  UNIQUE KEY (x)
);
```

MySQL seems to have a design flaw that allows deadlocks because it is *not* atomic for a statement to acquire locks on multiple unique keys.

Comment: what if needed, something like LOCK TABLES A READ, B WRITE, C WRITE;
also, didn't get the multiple primary key example, could you please explain.

Comment: lock tables A, B write; -> gives error.
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ', categories write' at line 1

Comment: I made a mistake in the syntax above (now edited to fix). Each table name must be followed by `WRITE` or `READ`. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html for details on the syntax.

Comment: As for the multiple keys: I showed an example above. A table that has both a primary key and a unique key is susceptible to deadlocks because one session locks the primary key, then a second session locks the unique key, then the first session waits for the unique key, then the second session waits for the primary key. It is unfortunate but MySQL doesn't acquire locks atomically.